# ¿Como simular un cursor al dar clic en un texto?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando simular un cursor sobre un texto, el cual es un párrafo `p` que no es `contenteditable`, usando un elemento `span` como `cursor`, este `span` lo posiciono usando las coordenadas el mouse, sin embargo, el método que estoy utilizando no funciona correctamente, es decir, el cursor simulado se mueve en el texto pero no se posiciona entre cada carácter, si no que se posiciona encima (en algunos casos si se posiciona entre los caracteres).

Ejemplo:

```js
var p = document.getElementById('paragraph'),
                caret = document.createElement('span'),


                //Temporal styles
                temp_styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null),
                body_font_size = parseInt(temp_styles.getPropertyValue('font-size'), 10);

            caret.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; display: inline-block; width: 1px; height: 1em; background: red;';
            caret.style.top = (p.getBoundingClientRect().y + 1) + 'px';
            document.body.appendChild( caret );


            //Evento principal
            p.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                var cursor_x_pos = event.clientX,
                    index = Math.floor( cursor_x_pos / (body_font_size / 2) );


                caret.style.left = (index * (body_font_size / 2)) + 'px';
            }, false);
```

```css
body{
                margin: 0px;
            }
            *{
                user-select: none;
            }
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Divido el tamaño de fuente entre 2 (solo lo hago así porque me da un mejor resultado que no hacerlo) y la posición `x` del mouse la divido entre el resultado de la división anterior, después, para definir la posición `x` del cursor simulado, multiplico el resultado anterior por el tamaño de la fuente, también dividida entre 2.

¿Cual es la manera correcta de lograrlo?

Comment: en resumen, tu problema es que queres simular un cursor en un texto? a que te refieres con eso? intentas que al usuario al posicionar el cursor en el texto se cambie la forma del puntero?

Comment: No, intento mostrar un indicador cuando el usuario pase el mouse sobre algún texto, esto debido a que tengo un drag and drop que uso con iconos, la idea es indicar a usuario el lugar donde se insertará el icono, pero los elementos de texto NO deben tener propiedad `contenteditable="true"`

Comment: te sugiero que cambies el titulo de tu pregunta, genera confusión